# APC not recommended for production?

Tags: php, apache, caching, apc

I have started having problems with my VPS in the way that it would faill to serve the pages on all the websites. It just showed a blank page, or offered to download the php file ( luckily the code was not in the download file :) ).
The server was still running, but this seemed to be a problem with PHP, since i could login into WHM.

If i did a apache restart, the sites would work again.

After some talks with the server support they told me this is a problem with the APC extension witch they considered to be old and not recommended for production servers. So they removed it for now, to see if the same kind of fails would continue to appear.

I haven't read anywhere that APC could have some problems or that its not always recommended to use, quite the contrary ... everywhere people are saying to always use it.

The APC extension was installed ssh and is the latest version.

**Edit:**
They also dont recomend MemCache and say that a more reliable extension would be eAccelerator

Comment: Who is they (your hosting support)? I'd like to add them to my list of companies to avoid.

Comment: they are a romanian company :-P

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is "VPS + APC = running out of resources" - are you sure you're not running out of memory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Um APC is current tech and almost a must for any performant PHP site.

Not only that but it will ship as **standard** in PHP 6 (rather than being an optional module like it is now).

I don't know what your issue is/was but it's not APC being outdated or old tech.

Answer (score 3):

I run several servers myself and the only time I have ever had trouble with APC was when trying to run it concurrently with Zend Optimizer. They don't work together so if I must use Optimizer (like if some commercial, third-party code requires it) I run eAccelerator instead of APC. Effectively 6 of one, half-dozen of another when it comes to performance but I really doubt APC is the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, memcached is only going to benefit you greatly if you are running multiple servers which need to access a shared data cache. Memcached does not do opcode caching like APC/eAccelerator/Xcache/etc.

Comment: Why the downvote? If anything i have written above is wrong, correct it! or at least point what could have been better...

Comment: James, your answer is about memcached, not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not to do with APC. If APC had a problem, it would either show up in your php log file or you simply wouldn't be able to access your website until you adjusted APC. The problem is more likely with apache itself. I've experience the same problem as you with blank pages before and it was to do with mod_security playing up and preventing pages from being sent that looked "suspicious". Also, memory usage in apache is good at killing the server under load. I've also had experience with a web host that had compiled apache with a memory leak so every X amount of requests (say 100,000) the server would crash! Most annoying.

Your web host doesn't sound the most competent out there as they are giving some bad advice, most likely based on ignorance.

APC should be used on production (with the mstat check turned off on production, but on for development). You can get more stats about your apc setup while it's working by loading the apc status file that comes with it and you get a nice page like this: http://drupal.org/files/images/APC%20Status-1.png

Memcache is very heavily used as it's also distributed! The use for such is as follows:

1. APC is the fastest as it works most closely to php, but only works on the same server executing the PHP itself so it's use is limited in that scope. Used primarily as an opcode cache.
2. Memcache is like a very fast database spread over many computers working as one unit. However, a powercut will wipe the lot!!! Hence why they are heavily used to remove preasure from the persistant database. Facebook and many other sites have hundreds of servers running memcache.

My advice would be to find a web host that understands PHP. Fighting web hosts is hard work about whos right and whos wrong... until you find a good one ;)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like they are pushing a product that they probably have referral kickbacks on.

I run my own servers (have for a while) and I've never had this problem, not any **MAJOR** problems with MemCache.